# Set the sed command parameter for a range of time

Tags: awk, sed, grep

This is my sample log file where i like to extract out from a very large log file

```
2017-05-30 23:11:34,629 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:14,638 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
2017-05-30 23:10:54,663 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.KeyboardInteractiveAuthentication - SSH: Sent SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST (Password Authentication): 
2017-05-30 23:10:36,415 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address /172.16.8.1:58222
2017-05-30 23:10:36,415 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:10:36,446 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=/172.16.8.1]
```

I would like to extract out the whole chunk of log from `23:10:36` to `23:11:34` using the `sed`but it's fail. I had tested `grep` and `awk` but no hope for my expected outcome. It's only give me the log occurred witihin `23:10:36` which i not my expected outcome.This is my command

```
sed -n '/23:10:36/,/23:11:34/p' stlog.txt
```

Anyone know how to let this works? it's only contain time without date because my program will get the current system time only and query the log base on current system time only.

Comment: As the log is in reverse order, the addresses also need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two issues here: 1) the log seems to be in reverse order, 2) you have multiple lines that match the "end" pattern.

<sub>(Though the final line has 23:10:36,446 which is later than 23:10:36,415 on the second-to-last line)</sub>

With the reverse order, you only get the lines matching `23:10:36` since `sed` starts printing when it sees that, and continues until it sees `23:11:34`, which isn't there.

Reversing the patterns (as below) would seem like a solution, but you'd still only get the first line that matches the end pattern, since the printing stops when that pattern is seen the first time.

```
sed -n '/23:11:34/,/23:10:36/p' stlog.txt
```

Here's an `awk` solution that should be able to work around that issue:

```
awk -vstart="23:11:34" -vend="23:10:36" \
  '$0 ~ start {p=1} $0 ~ end {e=1} e && $0 !~ end {p=0} p' stlog.txt
```

The variable `p` controls printing and is cleared only after the "end" pattern is seen (`e` is 1) *and* the current line no longer matches that pattern.